# how to evaluate the integral $\int_0^1 dx_1...dx_n\prod_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j^{b_i})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

I need to calculate the integral:
$$
\int_0^1dx_1...dx_n\prod_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j^{b_i})
$$
for some constants $a_{ij}$ and $b_i$.

Of course this can be simply done by expanding the terms in the product and calculating each integral which is trivial, but the problem is that there are $n^n$ different terms so this approach is impractical unless  $n$ is small.

Comment: you can bound it by the generalized AM-GM inequality

Comment: This seems to be integration for an $n\times n$ matrix entries, so you visualize it as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ . Or define the matrix integral to be on entries; I don't exactly your problem, but you can do more if you redefine the integration on matrices.